# "it is a tedious process" vs. "it is tedious"

Tags: word-usage

[Adapted From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tedious)

> Learning a new computer program **is a tedious process**.

I am aware the meaning of the whole sentence. I'd just like to know the difference between the sentence above and the one below.

> Learning a new computer program **is tedious**.

Does the former convey a stronger feeling? Is the latter more common as it is shorter?

---

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/process)

> process: a series of actions that you take in order to achieve a result

Comment: "Can be" is the only difference as that indicates not always. "Is", on the other hand, indicates always. I don't think it matters. There is no difference in the eyes of your readership, so why worry?

Comment: I bet you imagined the problem was with process. Not for me.

Comment: @BruceMurray Thank you. You are right. I refined the OP.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. I was trying to convey that maybe you had imagined that including "process" in the second phrase made a significant difference.  It does not make any difference.

Comment: The second sentence doesn't say that a **process** is involved. In theory (although the nature of *tedious* tends to belie at least some of this), learning a new computer program in the second sentence could take a fewer number of steps or involve a shorter amount of time. It's possible for something to be tedious, but involve only a single action. A single action is not a process. Only something with at least two actions can normally be considered a process. So, including *process* can make a significant difference, depending on context.

Comment: I meant the first sentence, but thanks for the correction.

Comment: ....and the rest of your comment is not relevant to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is between the adjective "tedious" and the noun phrase "tedious process", as predicates of "learning a new computer program".
Of course, "learning a new computer program" is always a process, but the speaker has the option to characterize it by an adjective or by a noun phrase, with almost no difference in meaning.

Comment: Thank you. Both are common, and neither is more formal than the other, right?

Comment: "Is tedious" has wider applicability than 'is a tedious process", so they won't be equally common. I don't see any difference in formality.

Comment: Thank you.  You please help me to make up a context where "is tedious" is applicable while "is a tedious process" is not?

Comment: Studying for tomorrow's exam is tedious. Getting a computer science degree can be a tedious process.

Comment: Thank you. Is studying an action or a process?