# Is "studying" an action or a process?

Tags: word-usage

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/process)

> process: a series of actions that you take in order to achieve a result

From the post ["it is a tedious process" vs. "it is tedious"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/251019/116345)

> Only something with **at least two actions** can normally be considered a process.

According to the same post, "studying for tomorrow's exam" is not a process. Could I call it an action?

When should I call studying a process? Could studying how to use MS excel be a process?

Comment: Studying for an exam certainly sounds like a process to me. I can think of several actions that normally go into such studying. I should note that nowhere in the post that you reference does anybody claim that studying for an exam is *not* a process—so that statement in your question seems to be a false claim. (I can see where you might have inferred that, but the statement is never explicitly made.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Studying for MS Excel is definitely an action.

According to the Cambridge definition you cited:

> process: a series of actions that you take in order to achieve a
> result

A good example of a process would be studying for a PhD degree. It would generally consist of several steps, like passing a qualifying exam, defending your dissertation, etc.

*Disclaimer: You can re-frame your action as process if you define it as multiple small steps.*

Answer (score 1):

Virtually any action can be conceived as a process in time. In fact, I am not sure that physicists would say that the idea of an action that takes no time at all is even meaningful.